# What is the purpose of Cursor Adapter?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

Now, I used ListView and ArrayAdapter to show data from sqlite. My old implementation is retrieve from db and set to arrayAdapter. Then set adapter in listview.

But now considering to move to efficient adapter. What if sqlite have thousands of records ? I knew I have to retrieve first 20 records then retrieve next items based on scroll. I wonder Can I get that implementation by using cursor adapter ? Or May I know better solution for that situation.

Answer (score 2):

When having thousands of records in a Database/Server response or whatever you are fetching the information from, the best practice is to do use "Lazy Loading" technique, basically what it does is, showing chunks of data sets to the user for example, 50 elements at the time, so, there's no need to load 950 elements that might not even be used, this technique improves considerably the application response and your memory too, now how you implement it is really up to you, there's a BaseAdapter class to do it on your own, or a good implementation of Cursor/Array adapters might do the trick as well.

Is important to mention that cursors have one advantage:

> Cursor lets Android manage resources more efficiently by retrieving
>   and releasing row and column values on demand.

Hope it helps!

Regards!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the main reason I use CursorAdapter is that the content will automatically change if the data in sqlite changes. I don't need to consider about refresh UI if something changes below.

Secondly, both the `query` of sqlite and `listview` already make some optimization you want. The sqlite will not give all the data on the moment of executing query by default. It uses a slide window to gradually give the query result. And `listview` also does not draw all the item at once, it draws the items as the user scrolls down.

Hope this helps, though doesn't exactly answer your question

Answer (score 0):

you can involve a thread which retrieve data from database and put into a Map or List. then when you need data like per 20 records when you scroll read from Map. it may help you.

> just make another layer between database and view.